# Is it that the engine seized?

Tags: engine, motorcycle

My bike (Karizma) suddenly stopped while riding it and there wasn't any engine oil...the mechanic told me the engine is seized.

After putting the oil he tried to kick start the bike but the kick had turned loose and he did not have any idea why is the engine not starting.

What i want to know is what is the reason to this? Is it that the engine seized? or it could be some other problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What exactly do you expect us to help with? Engines require oil to lubricate the many moving parts. No oil = seizure.

Comment: well the Mechanic had put the oil but the bike did not start

Comment: after putting the oil he tried to kick start the bike but the kick had turned loose and he did not have any idea why is the engine not starting

Comment: Again, how do you expect us to help? What is your question?

Comment: what i want to know is what is the reason to this ?

Comment: is it that the engine seized? or it could be some other problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you ran the engine without oil it will cause **serious internal engine damage**, including seizure of moving parts (bearings, piston rings, etc).

If the engine is stopped before serious damage has occurred, it might still operate after it cools down and oil is added. It sounds like that is what your mechanic attempted. Even if the engine is no longer seized, there is good possibility there is still damage.

From what you have described, it appears your engine has serious internal damage and will likely need to be rebuilt or replaced.

Comment: Clear and succinct, that engine needs work.